# admin_post hook not working

Tags: hooks, actions, forms

I have this inside the `<form></form>`:

```
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="submit_images" data-parsley-excluded />
```

I have this as my hook just to test:

```
function maybe_add($entry, $form) {
        wp_redirect( 'https://www.google.com/', 301 );
        exit();
}
add_action( 'admin_post_submit_images', maybe_add_', 10, 2 );
```

I never get redirected to google though no matter what I've tried. Any ideas?

Comment: you have an underscore after "maybe_add" in your `add_action`

Comment: does this action hook actually exist? where did you get your code from? what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a `'` in your code and your function name is different.

```
function my_maybe_add_redirect( $entry, $form ) {
    wp_redirect( 'https://www.google.com/', 301 );
    exit();
}
add_action( 'admin_post_submit_images', 'my_maybe_add_redirect', 10, 2 );
```